# Is there a Java coding standards? If so, is there a tool that will check for those standards?

Tags: java, standards

Are there Java coding standards?   If so, is there a tool that implements and checks for those standards?  I'm not familiar but hoping that someone has used Sonar, Checkstyle, PMD, Findbugs, Clover, and/or Cobertura that could tell me if any of those tools or other tools can do that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442167/existence-of-a-java-standard http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615348/is-there-a-coding-standard-for-java

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**. All of those tools can enforce coding styles (and more).

Comment: So what is the perfect set of tools?

Comment: The one that suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Sun's (now Oracle's) coding conventions documentation is here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

I've used Checkstyle to verify that my code follows these conventions as well as conventions adopted by organizations that I've worked for.

Comment: Is there a plugin for Checkstyle with those coding conventions?

Comment: Or do you have to implement them yourself?

Comment: I don't remember if Checkstyle's standard coding conventions are the same as Sun's/Oracle's, but they are a good starting point that you can use.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ can enforce coding styles and standards as well.  Its Inspector can also check for possible bugs as you write code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes all these tools will do what you want. You can also add custom rules if you need to. You can also get checkstyle and findbugs plugin for Eclipse.