# Java Coding standards

Tags: java

What coding standards in java should a programmer definitely 
follow for a more readable code?

Comment: This question will definetly lead to an unstoppable discussion because everyone has another opinion about that.

Comment: @Chris I do not 100% agree with that. There are some conventions that should really be followed like for example the naming conventions.

Comment: Maybe you're right but the answers to this question would be nothing better (rather worth) - readable and searchable than any search issued to any search engine on that topic. I think it would be pretty hard to filter out the few really useful answers.

Comment: Plus, even if one might consider this not subjective, the topic has been [covered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338080/java-programming-guidelines) [several](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197595/is-there-a-java-coding-standards-if-so-is-there-a-tool-that-will-check-for-thos) [times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442167/existence-of-a-java-standard) [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615348/is-there-a-coding-standard-for-java) (each with similar answers).

Comment: Some good compilation from different sources merged and actively maintained which is also `uptodate` http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html

Comment: Fyi https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_conventions

Answer (score 10):

Read the [Code Conventions for the Java programming language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html) by Oracle

Comment: link expired.......

Comment: Link is currently ok with a warning `The information on this page is for Archive Purposes Only

This page is not being actively maintained. Links within the documentation may not work and the information itself may no longer be valid. The last revision to this document was made on April 20, 1999`

Answer (score 5):

[Roger C. Martin: Clean code - a handbook of agile software development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)

Answer (score 3):

Start with [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) and [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-contents.html

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of factors which go into defining the term "a good coding standard" but the [official document](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html) should offer you some insight.